# Dynamic Placeholder substitution in properties in java

Tags: java, properties, placeholder

I wanted to substitute the placeholder dynamically in properties in a java application. Like

```
 WelcomeMessage=Welcome Mr. {firstName} {lastName} !!!
```

These firstName and LastName variable needs to be substituted dynamically. Should we use velocity template engine for the same? Or are there any other opensource frameworks for the same?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 53):

You can use the [MessageFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class of Java SE.  It allows you to do exactly what you ask for.

In your case the below code snippet must do the trick, assuming props contains all the properties loaded from your file.

```
MessageFormat.format((String) props.get("WelcomeMessage"), "First", "Last");
```

Note that your properties files should have index of parameters instead of named parameters as below.

```
WelcomeMessage=Welcome Mr. {0} {1} !!!
```

Comment: It does, yes, except that inexplicably, it's defined using numeric placeholders rather than meaningful symbolic ones. Amazing how much harder that is to use.

Comment: Edited my reply just as you were commenting.  :)

Answer (score 6):

Velocity is rather old and unpleasant, in my opinion, there are nicer ways to do this:

- [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) is the simplest of the template engines, and good enough for what you need (see syntax examples [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Five+minute+Introduction)).
- If you're already using Spring 3, it has the [PropertyPlaceholderHelper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.html) class which can do this also, but I wouldn't use Spring just to get hold of this one class.

Comment: Velocity is not perfect. However I think it does its job very well and I can recommend it very much. Furthermoe the toolbox concept allows very easy integration of your own "templating logic". And it has a great integration with Servlets in general (and Struts 1.x)

Answer (score 6):

One of the way is string substitutor:

```
WelcomeMessage=Welcome Mr. ${firstName} ${lastName} !!!
```

---

```
Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
valuesMap.put("firstName", "ram");
valuesMap.put("lastName", "Kumar");
StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
String message = sub.replace(WelcomeMessage);
```

Comment: The most recent version of this class is StringSubstitutor in org.apache.commons.commons-text

Answer (score 2):

Another option is adding [Apache FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) with no dependencies and define template as:

```
Welcome Mr. ${firstName} ${lastName} !!!
```

> Apache FreeMarker™ is a template engine: a Java library to generate text output (HTML web pages, e-mails, configuration files, source code, etc.) based on templates and changing data. Templates are written in the FreeMarker Template Language (FTL), which is a simple, specialized language

You can use [StringTemplateLoader](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/StringTemplateLoader.html) to load template using String

> you can create a StringTemplateLoader and add each template to it:

Answer (score 0):

velocity is the best tool as of now. But it depends on what file type you want to use as a template.

For example, if you want to use MS word docs as template, then you have to extend velocity classess and write your own implementation.

Comment: too heavy, too complicated

Answer (score 0):

In a Java web application with JSF 2 that would work as follows:

**src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\faces-config.xml**

```
...
    <resource-bundle>
      <base-name>com.mycompany.resources.messages</base-name>
      <var>mytext</var>
    </resource-bundle>
...
```

**src\main\resources\com\mycompany\resources\messages\mytext.properties**

```
WelcomeMessage = Welcome Mr. {0} {1} !!!
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{mytext.WelcomeMessage}" >          
  <f:param value="#{userSessionBean.first}" />
  <f:param value="#{userSessionBean.last}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```