# Java Scripting (JSR223) = Bean/Script Shells for templating?

Tags: java, linux, templates, scripting, jsr223

I have not yet used any `"java scripting" (JSR223)` and my question is related to linux (and windows).

Is there an easy way (after installing the scripting language and java) to do the following:

1. Run a Script (in the respective language) that imports a template
   (=a file with
   placeholders/variables).
2. That furthermore imports (read from filesystem) a config file with
   key=value pairs (java properties
   file)
3. And fills in the placeholder with the key-value pairs.
4. And writes the "merged" content into a file on the filesystem...

(This
    script should be easily be callable
    like "java scriptingenvironment
    scriptname myparameters")

Is this easily possible and/or have you done this before? And do you even know any links where this has been described/done before?

Thank you very much!!!!

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes very close: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve your goal by using a plain Java template engine such as [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) or [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) and standard filesystem and [properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) operations.  No need to use any java scripting (per JSR223) as you mention.

Comment: Hello maerics. Thanks for your answer. You are right in the sense, that velocity is a solution. I use velocity heavily for the view layer. But i thing for templating "on the file system level", it is a huge burden, if a all the time have to recompile stuff. what I want to have, that i edit any tempaltes/scripts and i do not have to compile but rather work in "realtime" with the scripts, like a shell script...

Answer (score 0):

Application objects can be bound as global variables in scripts via

```
ScriptEngine.put(String name, Object value);
```

You can do variable substitution as described in answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205627/dynamic-placeholder-substitution-in-properties-in-java) or use some **Spring** facility whose name escapes me at the moment.