# Spring Batch: Passing runtime parameters to query in ItemReader

Tags: sql, spring-batch

I have a spring batch program which reads from one database and writes to a file.

It has item reader as below:

```
<beans:bean id="myItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="jobRepository-dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="sql" value="${dbTofileDataReadSQL}"/>
    <beans:property name="rowMapper">
        <beans:bean class="com.mypackage.MyRowMapper" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

The sql is something like:

```
select one, two, three, four from myTable where business_date='12/12/11'
```

This line will go into my properties file:

```
dbTofileDataReadSQL = select one, two, three, four from myTable where business_date='12/12/11'
```

How to pass this business date at run time in the item reader so that it gets added in item reader.

Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [late-binding with step scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#late-binding) or a simple [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer)

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="path to your properties file, either classpath: ... or c:/... " />
</bean>
```

and if you need multi-line entries in your properties file, go like this

```
# sql, multiline property with \
sql=\
SELECT \
ID, \
NAME \
FROM TEST \
ORDER BY ID
```

Or starting from Spring 3, you can use SpEL:

```
<util:properties id="myProperties" location="..." />
...
<beans:bean ...
   <beans:property name="sql" value="#{myProperties.sql}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I reached at this solution.. However, I had the updated date available in some other table. So used inner query. Can you please check my other question about skipping Item Writer in a step.

Answer (score 0):

Have a placeholder in your property

```
dbTofileDataReadSQL = select one, two, three, four from myTable where business_date={0}
```

And check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2205654/344927) that shows how to resolve it at runtime using `MessageFormat` class

#### Update:

With Spring, if you have that property file added to your resource bundle,
you could retrieve the resolved value using `ApplicationContext#getMessage`

```
String getMessage(String code,
                  Object[] args,
                  Locale locale)
                  throws NoSuchMessageException
```