# Placeholder parser in Java

Tags: java, parsing, properties, lookup, placeholder

I'm preparing configuration some API service and I got stuck with the placeholder issue. I would like to allow user specify plain-text properties value as well as placeholder which will be looked up in some place. Lookup strategy will be provided.

All these will look like the following:

```
my_prop.properties
    my.plain.text.property=some_value
    my.property.to.look.up.somewhere=${look.it.up}
```

Is there some parser for these case? I'm pretty much sure that there is something. So I can extract plain-text value properties and resolve placeholders where needed.

Comment: may be this post will helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205627/dynamic-placeholder-substitution-in-properties-in-java

Comment: The Java Scripting API, with an eval (say for JavaScript) and a variable map would do: `s = engine.eval("'" + getProperty("my.ptlus") + "'");`. Or Expression Language.