# how to change values of Application.properties in Spring

Tags: java, spring, application.properties

Is there a way of changing values of a property in `Application.properties`

for example:

```
user.update.url = http://localhost:8080/user/{:userId}/update
```

Is there a way to create a proper url based on `{:userId}` without using `String.replace()` method?

```
http://localhost:8080/user/1/update 
http://localhost:8080/user/1/update 
http://localhost:8080/user/1/update
```

Currently, the horrendous implementation is as follows:

Application.properties:

```
user.update.url = http://localhost:8080/user/{:userId}/update
```

Class A:

```
public classs A{

  private int userId;

  @Value("${user.update.url}")
  private String url;

 public A(int userId){
  this.userId=userId
 }

  public String getUrl(){
    return url.replace("{:userId}",userId+"");
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does the value of userId come from initially?

Comment: @A.Ebrahim the value is coming from the controller class where we get the id of logged in user.

Comment: I have full freedom over changing the class. I thought having the url in application.properties would be nicer, if not I might have to construct the url manually each time from each class using it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205627/dynamic-placeholder-substitution-in-properties-in-java/52165713#52165713

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you could use the [`MessageSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) which is usually used to resolve i18n messages.

You can inject it :

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

and then call :

```
messageSource.getMessage(propertyKey, arrayOfParameters, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

For exemple, if you have the following key :

```
testKey.sample = Hello {0} ! {1}
```

calling :

```
messageSource.getMessage("testKey.sample", "man", "Bye", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

will output the message :

> Hello man ! Bye

By default, Spring looks for `messages.properties` files in the `src/main/resources` folder. You can configure it.

Comment: certainly cleaner than what I'm doing atm. I'll give it a go, thx